# Javascript: imported identifier is not known when exported correctly

Tags: javascript, module

I can't see why such a simple thing like exporting/importing an object/function in Js does not work as intended. Where is my error?

core.js:

```
import getPlugins from './plugins.js'
```

plugins.js:

```
export default () => {
  return ["blah/index.js"]
}
```

I always get the error:

```sh
import getPlugins from './plugins.js'
       ^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

WTF? AFAIK I am *declaring* the identifier here.

So I thought that exporting the default object (as function) is easy like this.

I tried everything. `module.exports =`, exporting named function:

```
module.exports = {
  getPlugins: () => {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Please help a JS beginner. Found no answer on all the tutorials/explains I saw - or - I didn't get it at least.

Comment: Seems like the environment you are executing the code in does not support ES6 modules.

Comment: @FelixKling or the files are not being imported as modules. If in the browser, the `<script>` type must be "module". In Node, things are slightly (but not much) more complicated.

Comment: @nerdoc note that the error you're getting is about the `import` keyword, not your identifier.

Comment: If this is about NodeJS, then [this article may help](https://blog.logrocket.com/es-modules-in-node-js-12-from-experimental-to-release/)

Comment: Thanks all of you. Yes, I stumbled upon the module mess in Js, which hopefully will be better with ES6 - great article @Pointy. The environment is webpack, which uses node internally? I changed the `import`  to require() and it worked.
AgainWhatLearned™.
Oh, and use that as answer - eh - both were correct and helpful. ;-)